# Neo4j queries very slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1

I set up a Neo4j 3.3.5 database with the following Labels:

- Tag: 30K
- Expert: 304K
- Publication: 28M

There are 1.2B relationships between tags and publications. And 455K relationships between publications and experts.

I've done tests on a Mac (16G - Java 9) and a Thinkpad (32G - Ubuntu Server Java 8). It's the same for both: very slow. My database on the disk is ~50G.

I have only one index on the tag name. It's the only criteria I've used.

The following query takes 8 seconds:

```
MATCH (expert:Expert)-[:PUBLISHED]->(publication:Publication)-[:HAS_TAG]->(tag:Tag)
USING INDEX tag:Tag(name)
WHERE tag.name IN ["Enzymes", "Metabolism", "Peptides"]
WITH expert, count(DISTINCT tag) AS relevantNumberOfTags, count(DISTINCT publication) AS relevantNumberOfPublications
WHERE relevantNumberOfTags = 3
RETURN expert.name, relevantNumberOfPublications
ORDER BY relevantNumberOfPublications DESC
LIMIT 40;
```

The EXPLAIN of the query is:

```
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Variables                                                                                     | Other                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |             40 | anon[311], anon[329], anon[335], relevantNumberOfPublications, expert, expert.name, ...       |                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |             40 | expert.name, relevantNumberOfPublications -- anon[311], anon[329], anon[335], ...             | {expert.name : , relevantNumberOfPublications : }                                                                                                                               |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Top              |             40 | anon[311], anon[329], anon[335], relevantNumberOfPublications, expert, relevantNumberOfTags   | anon[335]; 40                                                                                                                                                                   |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |           3243 | anon[329], anon[335] -- anon[311], relevantNumberOfPublications, expert, relevantNumberOfTags | { : expert.name,  :   relevantNumberOfPublications@255}                                                                                                                         |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |           3243 | anon[311], relevantNumberOfPublications, expert, relevantNumberOfTags                         | anon[311]                                                                                                                                                                       |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Projection       |           4324 | anon[311] -- relevantNumberOfPublications, expert, relevantNumberOfTags                       | {expert : expert, relevantNumberOfTags : relevantNumberOfTags,   relevantNumberOfPublications@255 :   relevantNumberOfPublications@255,  : relevantNumberOfTags = {  AUTOINT1}} |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation |           4324 | relevantNumberOfPublications, relevantNumberOfTags -- expert                                  | expert                                                                                                                                                                          |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +F ilter           |       18695308 | anon[22], anon[62], expert, publication, tag                                                  | tag.name IN {  AUTOLIST0}; tag:Tag                                                                                                                                              |
| |                  +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |       20141244 | anon[62], tag -- anon[22], expert, publication                                                | (publication)-[:HAS_TAG]->(tag)                                                                                                                                                 |
| |                  +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter           |         454092 | anon[22], expert, publication                                                                 | publication:Publication                                                                                                                                                         |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)      |         454092 | anon[22], publication -- expert                                                               | (expert)-[:PUBLISHED]->(publication)                                                                                                                                            |
| |                 +----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan  |         304114 | expert                                                                                        | :Expert                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I use size instead of using count, I won't have the relevant publications. I don't know how to optimise this query. It takes 8 seconds to return the result. So I don't know if it's normal because I wouldn't have enough RAM for example.

Comment: can you give us your slow queries ? Otherwise, it will be hard to help you

Comment: can you try this query to see if it's better, and give me the EXPLAIN of it : `MATCH (expert:Expert)-[:PUBLISHED]->(publication:Publication)-[:HAS_TAG]->(tag:Tag)
USING INDEX tag:Tag(name)
WHERE tag.name IN ["Enzymes", "Metabolism", "Peptides"]
WITH expert, count(DISTINCT tag) AS relevantNumberOfTags, count(DISTINCT publication) AS relevantNumberOfPublications
WHERE relevantNumberOfTags = 3
RETURN expert.name, relevantNumberOfPublications
ORDER BY relevantNumberOfPublications DESC
LIMIT 40;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've updated the question with your request and the EXPLAIN. It's the same response time.

Comment: The query plan is same, or normally if you have an index on :Tag(name), it should not be the same ! Can you check if you have this indes with `:schema` in the browser ?

Comment: Strange result! On my 16GB machine I had an index: 895s to return result. I removed the index, 57s. On my 32GB machine I had no index, 8s. After creating an index `CREATE INDEX ON :Tag(name);` or `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (t:Tag) ASSERT t.name IS UNIQUE;` then it took 570s. I'm very confused!

Comment: OK, so it's better to start your query from the expert (the set is small) than to start the query from the tag, that's all. So your index is not needed. If you want to speed this result, you need to add a link between the `Expert` and `Tags`

Answer (score 0):

With your query, you are doing a  scan of all your relationships, because the type of your relationship is dynamic.

For example if you do this, it will be really fast (Neo4j takes the count from its stats database) : `MATCH ()-[:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN count(*)`

If you have `APOC` and want to have some stats about your database, I recommend you  to use this procedure : `CALL apoc.meta.stats yield labelCount, relTypeCount, propertyKeyCount, nodeCount, relCount, labels, relTypes, stats`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your query is a lot better. I have another query that is more complicated, I will post another answer.